# whya are my ICONS not showing up CSS/Html?

Tags: html, css

What i am trying to do is show my icons. I want the facebook Icon, youtube and instagram icon to appear on the page.

This is the line of code where I am attempting 
to have the icons show.

```
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></a></li>

    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>

    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube-square"></i></a></li>

    </ul>
```

This is my whole page.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

  <title>RESUME</title>
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Resume.css">

  </head>

<body>
<div class="box">
<img src="pic.jpg" alt="" class="box-img">

<h1> Last name </h1>
<h5> Bachelors In Informatics</h5>
<p> 
This is the Greatest Resume of all time. Now don’t be so fast as to flip this over and toss it aside or better yet file it away with all the other
 boring old Resumes you must read through out the long workday. Stick around and see what I have to say, 
  you won’t regret it one bit;As the title stated this will be one of a kind it will blow your mind once you are finished here.
  So sit back relax pull out some of those snacks you got hidden away and enjoy the ride to your next best employee of the year!
</P>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></a></li>

    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>

    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube-square"></i></a></li>





    </ul>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

This is the css I am using. I am not sure if it's a problem with the css or the HTML causing it not to show up.

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: url(pic.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
.box{
    width:450px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    padding: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 5%;
    color: white;
    font-famimly; 'century Gothic' ,sans-serif;
    }

.box-img{
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    }

.box h1{
        font-size: 40px;
        letter-spacing 4px;
        font-weight: 100px;
        }

.box h5{
        font-family: 25px;
        letter-spacing: 3px;
        font-weight 100;
        }

.box p {
    text-align:justify;
    }

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    }
.box li{
        display: inline-block;
        margin; 6px;
        list-style: none;

        }

.box li a {
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 60px;
        transistion: all ease-in-out 250ms;


    }


 .box li a:hover{
 color: #b969b6;
 }
```

Comment: nothing in you code include something related to the icons

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use fontawesome but forgot to link in their css.

Comment: Your solution is right on FontAwesome's own 'How to Use' page... https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to include Font Awesome's css.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">`

Comment: I think better show him the CDN and hightlight the difference between the V4 and V5